# Display date in French

Tags: php

I was wondering if it was possible to display the month in a calendar in French ?

```
     $daysOfWeek = array('&nbsp;Lundi&nbsp;&nbsp;','&nbsp;Mardi&nbsp;&nbsp;','Mercredi','&nbsp;Jeudi&nbsp;&nbsp;','Vendredi','&nbsp;Samedi&nbsp;');
 $firstDayOfMonth = mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year);
 $numberDays = date('t',$firstDayOfMonth);
 $dateComponents = getdate($firstDayOfMonth);
 $monthName = $dateComponents['month'];

 $dayOfWeek = $dateComponents['wday'];
 if($dayOfWeek==0){
     $dayOfWeek = 6;
 }else{
     $dayOfWeek = $dayOfWeek-1;
 }

 
$datetoday = date('Y-m-d');



$calendar = "<table>";
$calendar .= "<h2>$monthName $year</h2>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you could use the PECL [intl](https://www.php.net/manual/book.intl.php) module

  ```php
  $date = new DateTime();
  $formatter = new IntlDateFormatter('fr_FR');
  $dateFormatter = \IntlDateFormatter::create(
      \Locale::getDefault(),
      \IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
      \IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
      \date_default_timezone_get(),
      \IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
      'EEEE MMMM'
  );
  var_dump($dateFormatter->format($date)); // string(13) "lundi janvier"
  ```
- Else, with a simple array and `date('n')` and `date('N')`. See [DateTime::format()](https://www.php.net/manual/datetime.format.php) for formats.

  ```php
  $days   = ['Lundi','Mardi','Mercredi','Jeudi','Vendredi','Samedi','Dimanche'];
  $months = ['Janvier','Février','Mars','Avril','Mai','Juin','Juillet','Août','Septembre','Octobre','Novembre','Décembre'];

  $timestamp = 1643660449; // Example. Should be your mktime()
  $monthName = $months[date('n', $timestamp) - 1];
  $dayName   = $days[date('N', $timestamp) - 1];

  echo "$dayName $monthName"; // Lundi Janvier
  ```
- Finally, note that [strftime()](https://www.php.net/manual/function.strftime) allows to format a date, but is now deprecated.

Some additional notes:

1. Don't use `&nbsp;` in your array, but only when displaying your string (maybe take a look to margins/padding using CSS)
2. The `<h2>` tag cannot be the first child of a `<table>` tag.